# Clickable overlay YouTube using Safari on IOS

Tags: mobile-safari, youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube API to display a video in the browser that takes up the entire viewable area.  In every other browser I've tried it on (Chrome 23, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome on Android), the close icon overlay is clickable while the video is playing (click link, see top right):

http://jsbin.com/ajivex/2

It doesn't work in Safari on IOS 5.1.1.  Is there anything I can do aside from creating a header and forcing the video not to take up the full height of the viewable area?

Comment: Seeing that behavior here too... That's a bummer. Did it actually work before?

Comment: I never saw it working in IOS.  I stopped using full screen and just put the close button above the video.  The user can full screen the video if they really want I guess...